# Sqlplus script part showing "Badly placed ()'s." error

Tags: shell, sqlplus, io-redirection, csh

I'm writing a script and have a problem when trying to get a date from the table. I'm having problem storing it into a variable. I always get the error:
Badly placed ()'s.

The variable TIMEFRAME is "D" and the shell actually gets into the IF, also the password is also not the problem as I use it to connect manually and check the query (no problems here).

This is the part of the script where I'm having problems.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
if ( $TIMEFRAME == "D" ) then
   set TIMEBEG = `sqlplus -s $PASSWORD << EOF \
   set head off; \
   set feed off; \
   select to_char(trunc(sysdate) - 1,'YYYYMMDD') from dual; \
   exit; \
EOF`
set TIMEEND = $TIMEBEG"235959"
set TIMEBEG = $TIMEBEG"000000"
endif
```

I also tried to store it on a file, same problem

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set tmp_file=/tmp/tmp.$$
if ( $TIMEFRAME == "D" ) then
   sqlplus -s $PASSWORD > $tmp_file << EOF \
   set head off \
   set feed off \
   select to_char(trunc(sysdate) - 1,'YYYYMMDD') from dual; \
   exit; \
EOF
set TIMEBEG=`cat $tmp_file`
set TIMEEND = $TIMEBEG"235959"
set TIMEBEG = $TIMEBEG"000000"
endif
```

I tried different solutions but with the same problem, tried without semi-colons, without the SETs, to put it on a single line, I'm out of Ideas.

When trying with -xvf this is what I get when I get into the part:

```
if ( $TIMEFRAME == "D" ) then
if ( D == D ) then
sqlplus -s $PASSWORD > $tmp_file << EOF set head off set feed off select to_char ( trunc ( sysdate ) - 1,'YYYYMMDD' ) from dual ; exit ; EOF
Badly placed ()'s.
```

Any ideas? This is running on Amazon Linux

Comment: Why are you scripting in csh?

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: Because of my Work, that is why :(

Comment: You don't need the backslashes do you?  I think the shell thinks the anchor  variable is `EOF set head off set feed off select to_char ( trunc ( sysdate ) - 1,'YYYYMMDD' ) from dual ; exit ; EOF` instead of the `EOF` you expected.  See http://tomecat.com/jeffy/tttt/cshredir.html

Comment: Ohhh I tried a lot of stuff without backlashes but the second code that I posted without the backlashes worked :). Thank you everyone.

Comment: @ErickRecio  The only difference between them is whether the output is put in a file and that doesn't affect the input, so both of them should work without backslashes.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thank you for your help, but the first one without the backlashes didn't worked, It was one of the first things I tried, I really tried different solutions, I added/removed/changed a lot of stuff, none worked.

```if ( $TIMEFRAME == "D" ) then
if ( D == D ) then
set TIMEBEG = "`sqlplus -s $AIM_PSWD << EOF
Unmatched ".
```

Comment: @ErickRecio  Yes, I missed the fact that you were using backticks.  That first one definitely doesn't work without the backslashes, just like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use a here-doc inside backticks in C shell.

Write the sqlplus input to a file, rather than writing the whole sqlplus command.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set tmp_file=/tmp/tmp.$$
if ( $TIMEFRAME == "D" ) then
    cat > $tmp_file <<EOF
    set head off
    set feed off
    select to_char(trunc(sysdate) - 1, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual;
    exit;
EOF
    set TIMEBEG = `sqlplus -s $PASSWORD < $tmp_file`
    set TIMEEND = $TIMEBEG"235959"
    set TIMEBEG = $TIMEBEG"000000"
endif
```